# How do you give user feedback after an action was made?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Using asp.net mvc, a user updates his profile. This is how my update action looks:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUser(string id, UserEditViewModel model)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<UserEditViewModel, SimpleUser>();
        var user = Mapper.Map<UserEditViewModel, SimpleUser>(model);

        userService.EditUser(user);

        //Re-populating the countries.
        var countries = geoService.GetCountries();
        model.Countries = countries.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.CountryId.ToString() });


        return View(model);
    }
```

First of all, am I doing this correct? By writing the countries populating code twice (1 in GET and 1 here).

Second, how do I give the user some form of a feed back that they have successfully updated their profile?

Comment: Could just add a flag to your model to toggle an "update successful" message.  Or maybe a boolean and a string so you can also render some sort of an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've created a specific view model for the user edit page (nice approach, by the way), I would actually add the message as a property on that view model itself.  After all, it exists specifically to contain data for your view, so why complicate things/add inconsistency by throwing a key/value pair into `ViewData`?  That's the way I see it at least.

Oh, and incidentally, if you're using Automapper, and it looks like you are (another nice approach) you may consider putting your `Mapper.CreateMap` in someplace other than the action itself.  There is a little overhead there.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the automapper tip, could you explain alittle more about how to move it from the action?

Comment: @Lol coder: You could move your `Mapper.CreateMap` calls into the constructor, that'd probably be the easiest.  Nothing else would have to change--so you can still continue to call `Mapper.Map` just like you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we will normally have to query twice, first to popule the screen and the second time to re-populate. You can always cache the values on the first retrieve and use the cached values on the postback action to re-populate the screen.

Set your message in ViewData (MVC-2) or ViewBag (MVC-3) and display to the user.

Comment: So something like ViewData["Success"] = true?

Comment: @Lol coder - yes, that is one method, or `ViewData["Message"] = "Profile updated";`, then you can display the contents on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- redirect to a different view that contains an 'update successful' message
- redirect to the 'Details' view (they will understand and 'see' that their changes have been saved)
- pass a message to the view through the `ViewData`/`ViewBag`, then the view can display this.
  You could even have that logic in your layout page so that any view can display a message at the top of the screen, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to create a common / helper method for your model for all this stuff, something like:

```
  private void SetupCountries() {
       //Re-populating the countries.
       var countries = geoService.GetCountries();
       model.Countries = countries.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Name, Value = c.CountryId.ToString() });
  }
```

Then in all of your actions in the controller, you can just call it without typing those code again.

```
  public ActionResult EditUser(.... {
     SetupCountries();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use

```
TempData["StatusMessage"] = "Your messsaga"
```

You can use tempdata for stuff only needed till next request.